# ERC-20 allowance, transferFrom functions

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20

I went through the IERC-20 interface and everything was pretty crystal clear, (hats off to whoever wrote the comments), but at the "allowance" and the "transferFrom" functions, I do not understand the two.

Can anyone please help explain?

```
/**
* @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
* allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
* zero by default.
*
* This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
*/
   function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

/**
     * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
     * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
     * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
     * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
     * desired value afterwards:
     * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    /**
     * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `from` to `to` using the
     * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
     * allowance.
     *
     * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24465/help-needed-understanding-erc20-smart-contract-functions-and-workflow?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If a smart contract want to spend [NumberofToken] user's ERC20 tokens must to ask a permission to read into user wallet and spend his tokens.
The user, for give the access to wallet to the smart contract, must to set the address of smart contract (in this case the smart contract is the spender) and maximum amount his tokens that the smart contract can spend.

Example:
I want to deposit a 20 LINK in a smart contract. I must to give access to my wallet to the smart contract using the `approve()` function and setting the amount of tokens that smart contract can spend from my wallet (in this case max. 20 LINK). After I called the `approve()` function the smart contract can access to my wallet and take my 20 LINK with `transferFrom()` function.

Now, with the example above, the `allowance()` function allow to see how many tokens remaining to spend for the smart contract.

Example:
Correlated to example described above, I called the `approve()` function with 20 LINK that smart contact can spend from my wallet. But the smart contract taking itself only 15 LINK. In this case when I'll call the allowance() function it'll return me the value: 5 LINK (20-15).

And the `transferFrom()` function allow to transfer the token from your wallet to smart contract or viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer that is already given, it may be interesting to touch on *why* this `approve()` + `transferFrom()` system exists.

Generally smart contracts have functions that you need to call to trigger certain functionality, e.g. swapping assets with Uniswap. When you want to send ETH to these functions (e.g. to swap ETH for DAI), these smart contract functions can be marked `payable` and you can directly send ETH while also calling the function at the same time.

This `payable` functionality does not exist for ERC20 tokens, only for ETH. So a different system needed to be developed to send ERC20 tokens while also calling a smart contract at the same time (e.g. to swap DAI for ETH). This is where the approval system comes in. You can grant the smart contract allowance to take your ERC20 tokens, and then call the smart contract function that you want to call. The smart contract can then "pull" the required tokens from your wallet in that function call.

I wrote an article on my blog in 2020 that goes into more detail about this: *[Unlimited ERC20 allowances considered harmful](https://kalis.me/unlimited-erc20-allowances/)*.